# Migrating Data from MongoDB to Postgres Using Python Script. Able to load the data in Postgres but only in 1st Column in JSON Format

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql

I loaded the data from Mongo to Postgres with python script but, I am not able to place the values in with respective columns of the Postgres. Data is in JSON Format.

```
import import psycopg2
from pymongo import MongoClient
from decimal import Decimal
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from datetime import datetime
import time

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return float(o)
        if isinstance(o, Decimal128):
            return float(str(o))
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://reporting:reporting123@miramira.ntara.mongodb.net")
db=client.Bookstore
col=db.Book
mdbcur=col.find()
with psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",
    database="Book",
    user="postgres", 
    password="root") as pgconn:
    pgcur=pgconn.cursor()

    for doc in mdbcur:
        print(doc)
        data=json.dumps(doc, cls=JSONEncoder)
        query_sql = """insert into booktable VALUES ('""" + data + """'::jsonb)"""
        pgcur.execute(query_sql)
        pgconn.commit()
        time.sleep(1)
    pgcur.close()
    mdbcur.close()
```

I need to load the data in the string format in each respective column of Postgres

[As you can see in the picture the way how data is loaded in the id column in JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMAJC.jpg)